# Ignore newlines in a regex that doesn't care about order

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex [here at scriptular.com](http://scriptular.com/#(%3F%3D.*net)(%3F%3D.*income)(%3F%3D.*total)(%3F%3D.*depreciation)%7C%7C%7C%7Ci%7C%7C%7C%7C%5B%22Net%20income%2Floss%2C%22%2C%22Total%20depreciation%20and%20amortization%20-%20Cash%20flow%2C%22%2C%22Other%20non-cash%20items%2C%22%2C%22Total%20non-cash%20items%2C%22%2C%22Change%20in%20accounts%20receivable%2C%22%2C%22Change%20in%20inventories%2C%22%2C%22Change%20in%20accounts%20payable%2C%22%2C%22Change%20in%20accounts%20payable%20and%20accrued%20liability%2C%22%2C%22Change%20in%20income%20taxes%2C%22%2C%22Change%20in%20assets%2Fliabilities%2C%22%2C%22Total%20change%20in%20assets%2Fliabilities%2C%22%2C%22Operating%20activities%20-%20Other%2C%22%2C%22Cash%20flow%20from%20operating%20activities%2C%22%2C%22Net%20change%20in%20property%2C%20plant%2C%20and%20equipment%2C%22%2C%22Net%20change%20in%20intangible%20assets%2C%22%2C%22Net%20acquisitions%2Fdivestitures%2C%22%2C%22Net%20change%20in%20short-term%20investments%2C%22%2C%22Net%20change%20in%20long-term%20investments%2C%22%2C%22Net%20change%20in%20investments%20-%20Total%2C%22%2C%22Investing%20activities%20-%20Other%2C%22%2C%22Cash%20flow%20from%20investing%20activities%2C%22%2C%22Net%20long-term%20debt%2C%22%2C%22Net%20current%20debt%2C%22%2C%22Debt%20issuance%2Fretirement%20net%20-%20Total%2C%22%2C%22Net%20common%20equity%20issued%2Frepurchased%2C%22%2C%22Net%20preferred%20equity%20issued%2Frepurchased%2C%22%2C%22Net%20total%20equity%20issued%2Frepurchased%2C%22%2C%22Total%20common%20and%20preferred%20stock%20dividends%20paid%2C%22%2C%22Financial%20activities%20-%20Other%2C%22%2C%22Cash%20flow%20from%20financial%20activities%2C%22%2C%22Foreign%20exchange%20rate%20adjustment%2C%22%2C%22Discontinued%20operations%20and%20miscellaneous%20cash%20flow%20adjustments%2C%22%2C%22Increase%2Fdecrease%20in%20cash%2C%22%2C%22Beginning%20cash%2C%22%2C%22End%20cash%2C%22%2C%22Stock-based%20compensation%2C%22%2C%22Common%20stock%20dividends%20paid%2C%22%2C%22Preferred%20stock%20dividends%20paid%22%5D)

```
/(?=.*net)(?=.*income)(?=.*total)(?=.*depreciation)/i
```

How do I make the regex successfully match the string?

Without the newline characters in the string, the regex would succeed. I could remove them... but I'd rather not.

Comment: You want to match only these words?

Comment: I don't care about regex match groups, I just want to be able to use regexObj.test(str) to see if the string contains what I want. Yes, I just care about the given example's words.

Comment: In JS there is no flag available to make the dot match newlines. Workarounds are use of [`[\s\S]`, `[\w\W]` or `[^]`](https://www.regex101.com/r/hEeXMg/1). To avoid timeout also consider anchoring the lookaheads to `^` start and using [lazy matching](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) by putting `?` after the `*` quantifier.

Comment: What about the "doesn't care about order" part? do you truly want to match the words in any order, unlike what the regex does now?

Comment: the regex now does not care about order. It will match "net income total depreciation" or "total depreciation net income"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.) The [dot](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) matches any character besides newline. It won't skip over newlines if the desired words would match in lines after the first one. In many regex flavors there is the *dotall* or *single line* `s`-[flag](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) available for making the dot also match newlines but unfortunately not in JS Regex.

Workarounds are to use a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) that contains any character. Such as `[\s\S]` any *whitespace character* `\s` together with any *non whitespace* `\S` or `[\w\W]` for any *word character* together with any *non word character* or even `[^]` for *not nothing* instead of the dot.

2.) [Anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) the lookaheads to `^` start of string as it's not wanted to repeat the lookaheads at any position in the string. This will drastically improve performance.

3.) Use [lazy matching](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) for being satisfied with first match of each word.

```
/^(?=[\s\S]*?net)(?=[\s\S]*?income)(?=[\s\S]*?total)(?=[\s\S]*?depreciation)/i
```

[See demo at regex101](https://www.regex101.com/r/hEeXMg/1) (dunno why this doesn't work in your demo tool)

Additionally you can use [`\b` word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) around the words for making sure such as `net` won't be matched in `brunet`, `network`... so the regex becomes `^(?=[\s\S]*?\bnet\b)`...